# How can I create an ASP.NET Identity user that can sign in?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.NET web application that has internal individual user accounts. I want to create those user accounts from an external program. So I have a program that references `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity`. In it I create users:

```
var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
var um = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
//...
var newUser = new IdentityUser(userName);
newUser.Email = userName;
var result = um.Create(newUser, "P@ssword1");
```

However, when I run the first application and try to sign in, `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` always returns `SignInStatus.Failure`. (I'm quite sure the username and password are correct; I'm copying the username from the database and copying the password from the code.) Shouldn't it work? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the culprit was `IdentityUser`. I don't know why (I'm guessing securitystamp has something to do with it), but you need to make `ApplicationUser`s. So I included a reference to the web application so I could make an `ApplicationUser` instead of an `IdentityUser`:

```
var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
var um = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
//...
var newUser = new ApplicationUser();
newUser.Email = user.UserName;
newUser.UserName = user.UserName;
var result = um.Create(newUser, "P@ssword1");
```